# Edit user signature, but can't use Oauth

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I'm tryng to edit the users signature via GAS.

I have found lots of examples and tutorials, and one of the Waqar Ahmad's answers looks very good - [Email Settings APIs Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805665/email-settings-apis-authentication).
However, it doesn't work for me.

I don't really understand OAuth autorization, but couldn't find a tutorial for it.

With what should I replace `anonymous`?

```
oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
```

I go to https://console.developers.google.com/ create a project and use clientID for key and client secret for secret, is it right?

Adding more information:

This is the Waqar's code I'm using:

```
     /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    This function will update the HTML signature of a user.
    Input will be jason data
    To disable signature, pass an empty string as signature value
    sample parameter
    ob = {user='hps', signature='<b>Regards</b><br>Waqar'}

    To disable signature
    ob = {user='hps', signature=''}
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function updateSignature(ob) {
      //ob = {};
      //ob.user = "hps";
      //ob.signature = "<b>Regards</b><br>Waqar";

      ob = {};
      ob.user = "test@xxxx.it";
      ob.signature = "<b>Regards</b><br>Waqar";
      var base = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/';
      var xmlRaw = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
          '<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">'+
          '<apps:property name="signature" value="'+htmlEncode(ob.signature)+'" />'+
          '</atom:entry>';
      var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('emailSetting',base);
      fetchArgs.method = 'PUT';
      fetchArgs.payload = xmlRaw;
      fetchArgs.contentType = 'application/atom+xml';
      var domain = UserManager.getDomain();
      var url = base+domain+'/'+ob.user+'/signature';
      var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);
      var status = urlFetch.getResponseCode();
      return status;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //This function will retreive Signature settings as json.
    /*Sample returned object
    {user=hps, signature=<b>Regards</b><br>Waqar}
    */
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    function retrieveSignature(user) {
      var user = 'hps';
      var base = 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/';
      var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('emailSetting',base);
      fetchArgs.method = 'GET';
      var domain = UserManager.getDomain();
      var url = base+domain+'/'+user+'/signature?alt=json';
      var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);
      var jsonString = urlFetch.getContentText();
      var jsonArray = Utilities.jsonParse(jsonString).entry.apps$property;
      var ob = {};
      ob.user = user;
      for(var i in jsonArray){
        ob[jsonArray[i].name] = jsonArray[i].value;
      }
      return ob;
    }
    //Google oAuthConfig.. 
    function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
      var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
      oAuthConfig.getAccessTokenUrl()
      oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
      oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
      oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com");
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx");
      return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
    }


    //This function will escape '<' and '>' characters from a HTML string
    function htmlEncode(str){
      str = str.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
      return str.replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
    }
```

to get the  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey and oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret I have created a new project in the google developer console, modified to on the Admin SDK API status, created a "Client ID for native application" and used the CLIENT ID in setConsuperKey, and CLIENT SECRET in setConsumerSecret.

Executing the script updateSignature the test@xxxx.it's signature should be changed,
I can see the box "autorization required" clik ok, and appear the request access box,
i click on "grant access" but nothing happes, and no error are shown.

Executing the same function in debug mode, i have the same boxes and a red box with "Errore OAuth" at the end.

I'm doing something wrong... please help me to find the mistake!!

Thanks again.

Marco

Comment: Why nobody replied the question? Is it not clear or too basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the clue!!

Thank's to mike's [quastions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393995/creating-a-group-with-admin-sdk-directory-api-in-google-apps-script-error-403?rq=1)

who let me discover [This example](http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/01/11/google-apps-script-to-create-signature-block-for-user/)

I Finally understand!!

- in **consumerkey** you have to set your domain (p.e. "mydomain.it",
- in **consumerSecret** you have to set the "**Secret data of the customer to OAuth:**" from admin google console->secority->advanced settings->Manage data OAuth key and secret for this domain.

I was confusing by the secret key in the google developer console, may be this answer can help